# How to translate "I have always been"

Tags: translation, grammar, past-tense

I have always struggled with this translation, but have never quite figured it out. How do I translate

> I have always been ...

Some examples would be:

- I have always been an academic
- I have always struggled with this translation
- I have always told you to be more mindful of others

I think the first one would best be translated as

> 我从来（都／就）是个 （academic)

But using ”从来“ doesn't seem to work quite well for the other two.

Comment: Consider using 一直.

Comment: If we speak in Cantonese, "我不嬲都係"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options. As @NS.X. pointed out 一直 is a good one, but you can also use

一向, e.g.我一向很懒。I have always been very lazy.

向来, e.g. 她向来就是个书呆子。 She has always been a bookworm.

---

从来 is more likely used together with 不 or 没 conveying negation, of course that is not necessary.

A conjecture of mine: 一直 is often used with a certain beginning in the speaker's mind, which is not always pointed out of course. 自从饭后我一直忙的很。Since dinner I have been very busy.

Answer (score 2):

长期以来

e.g.

I have always been feeling pain in both knees.

我长期以来两边（儿）膝盖疼。